# How module.export caching works in node

Tags: node.js

I have read everywhere that module.exports is cached and returns the same object everytime required is called after first call.
Here is my code-
index.js

```
var http= require('http');    
var Customer= require('./code/Customer');
var Wishlist= require('./code/Wishlist');

var server= http.createServer(function(req,res){

console.log("Request received");


res.end("Request received");


});

server.listen(3000,function(){

    console.log("hello");

    });
```

customer.js

```
var emitter= require('../../lib/EventDispatcher')();
emitter.on('wishlist',function(){

console.log("Listened to wishlist event");

});

module.exports= function(){

console.log("Inside customer");
}
```

Wishlist.js

```
var emitter= require('../../lib/EventDispatcher')();

module.exports= function(){

console.log("Inside customer");
emitter.emit('wishlist');
}
```

EventDispatcher.js

```
var emitter= require('events').EventEmitter;

module.exports= function() {

console.log("created"); 
return new emitter();
}
```

If my eventDispatcher is cached then event emitted by wishlist should be catched by customer. But its not happening.

I am trying to create a backbone for observers so that every module can listen for events on their own.Is it the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EventDispatcher module is cached, but each time you use it, you're calling the module constructor function again and that constructor function creates a new emitter object each time.  So, each time you use EventDispatcher, you're going to end up with a new and separate emitter because you're calling a new constructor each time.

FYI, I don't see the point of the EventDispatcher module.  It wraps EventEmitter, construction but doesn't do anything.  The callers might as well just create their own EventEmitter object directly.

To get a single global EventEmitter object, you can change your module to this:

```
var Emitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var sharedEmitter = new Emitter();

module.exports= function() {
    console.log("created"); 
    return sharedEmitter;
}
```

Comment: I want a global eventEmitter object  so that later when I add new modules, they should be able to observe events fired in other module. Is there any other way to do that? I just thought that if the exports would be cached then all modules will get the same eventEmitter object. One way I figured out is to create an eventEmitter in index file and inject it into every module in constructor. But that seems to be highly coupled. Pardon me if I am wrong.

Comment: @KrrishRaj - see what I added to my answer if you want a single shared emitter object.